# How to select Dataframe columns by conditional row value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to select every column of the dataframe with an ask value above 0.

```
           1INCHBTC  1INCHBUSD  1INCHUSDT  ...   ZRXBUSD       ZRXETH    ZRXUSDT
  ask      0.000075     4.3085     4.2992  ...    1.7418     0.000861     1.7392
  askQty  79.000000  1068.4500   225.4900  ...  959.4400   615.000000  1087.5000
  bid      0.000075     4.2976     4.2949  ...    1.7359     0.000851     1.7363
  bidQty   1.500000     6.3600    81.3400  ...  247.3700  6672.000000    28.7900
```

I figured `a.loc['ask'] > 0` would give a table of boolean True/False assignments. But I am looking for a list of matching column indexes only

```
In [34]: a.loc['ask'] > 0
Out[34]: 
1INCHBTC      True
1INCHBUSD     True
1INCHUSDT     True
AAVEBKRW     False
AAVEBNB       True
             ...  
ZRXBNB       False
ZRXBTC        True
ZRXBUSD       True
ZRXETH        True
ZRXUSDT       True
Name: ask, Length: 1382, dtype: bool
```

Comment: In the dataframe 'ask' is a row index?

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh yes

Comment: you have the condition ready, use it to mask the columns: `a.columns[a.loc['ask'] > 0]` ?

Comment: @AnuragDabas that would give a list of boolean values, but I am looking for a list of matching column indexes i.e. 1INCHBTC, 1INCHBUSD, etc.

Comment: `(a.loc['ask'] > 0).index.tolist()`

Comment: @anky `a.columns[a.loc['ask'] > 0]`seems to be working, thank you!